# Can't execute a php script without using "php" command before

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I need to use a php script without "php" command.

For example:

```
$ ./test.php
```

Permissions are sets to 755.

This is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

/usr/bin/php -v (so path exists)

returns

```
PHP 7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2017 08:53:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

This is the error I'll get everytime:

```
Exception: Zend Extension ./test.php does not exist
```

Also calling script with fullpath I'll get same error.

Calling this it works properly

```
$ php ./test.php
```

Any idea?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your php.ini, in my environment it works. Maybe you exported an environment variable for the search path php uses? Or it's the OPcache

Comment: Try `dos2unix test.php` then re-try. Mine works fine like @Psi so you may have windows style line endings. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/239927/usr-bin-php-sometimes-not-working-on-12-10-server

Comment: In a linux server? rather not. And as far as I can see, Claudio uses a debian. And I typed that file manually in vi, no upload involved

Comment: I think is something related of how I've uploaded the file... I've used phpstorm but creating the file with vi it works. Maybe an encoding related issue.

Comment: Yes, found the problem. Not encoding but ending line format. Unix ok, windows not.

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question. You found the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NOTE: The author found the solution and put it up in the comments but never posted an actual answer, so this answer is just clarifying what the author already said above so as to make the answer more obvious.

I was also getting the `Exception: Zend Extension does not exist` when I was trying to pipe an email via cpanel forwarder into a php script.

I opened the file in my editor (Komodo Edit on Windows) and went to EDIT > CURRENT FILE PREFERENCES and noticed that LINE ENCODINGS was set to `DOS/Windows (\r\n)`

I changed the LINE ENCODING to `UNIX (\n)` and saved it and re-uploded it and the error went away and all is good now.

Obviously the steps will vary depending on what editor you use, but the solution is to make sure your Line Encodings are UNIX and not DOS/Windows.

Comment: It worked like a charm. saved a lot time. used VsCode to convert Line-Encodings from win to unix

Comment: I had temporarily set `autocrlf` to true and forgot to reset it. it messed up all my PHP files. I removed the git setting, re-cloned and no more Zend error!

Answer (score 1):

Just run dos2unix on the file

```
# ./database.php 
Exception: Zend Extension ./database.php does not exist


# apt install dos2unix


# dos2unix database.php 
dos2unix: converting file database.php to Unix format...

# ./database.php
Yeah!!! It work's!!!!
```